# Audio samples per second?

Tags: audio, sampling

I am wondering on the relationship between a block of samples and its time equivalent. Given my rough idea so far:

Number of samples played per second = total filesize / duration.

So say, I have a 1.02MB file and a duration of 12 sec (avg), I will have about 89,300 samples played per second. Is this right?

Is there other ways on how to compute this? For example, how can I know how much a byte[1024] array is equivalent to in time?

Comment: Do you have any information about the audio format (sampling frequency, sample precision) ? The answer to your question can be directly calculated from those.

Comment: Im using a .WAV file, sample rate 44.1khz, 16-bit and mono.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking for PCM samples you can divide the total length (in bytes) by the duration (in seconds) to get the **number of bytes per second** (for WAV files there will be some inaccuracy to account for the header). How these translate into samples depends on

1. the sample rate
2. bits used per sample, i.e. commonly
   used is 16 bits = 2 bytes
3. number of channels, i.e. for stereo
   this is 2

If you know 2) and 3) you can determine 1)

In your example 89300 bytes/second, assuming stereo and 16 bits per sample would be 89300 / 4 ~= 22Khz sample rate

Comment: All good points, but there may also be compression to deal with.

Comment: @Paul R: There is no compression involved for PCM, for other formats this answer does not apply - there is no easy conversion since most formats don't even use a constant bit rate (i.e. most WMA and MP3).

Comment: yes, true, but the OP didn't say he was working with PCM data, hence the comment.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to @BrokenGlass's very good answer, I'll just add that for *uncompressed* audio with a fixed sample rate, number of channels and bits per sample, the arithmetic is fairly straightforward. E.g. for "CD quality" audio we have a 44.1 kHz sample rate, 16 bits per sample, 2 channels (stereo), therefore the data rate is:

```
  44100 * 16 * 2
= 1,411,200 bits / sec
= 176,400 bytes / sec
= 10 MB / minute (approx)
```